# Replacing multiple special characters from a file with a perl one-liner

Tags: regex, perl, unix, replace, special-characters

I'm trying to replace some special characters`(Ascii characters 1,5,7,23,26,30)` from a file.
I want to do it with a one-liner so I tried using the following.

```
perl -pi -e 's/([\x1 \x5 \x7 \x17 \x1a \x1e])//eg' dummy.txt
```

It replaces the special characters fine but I see there are some spaces also being removed from the file. For Ex: `1257 ST 02 BW` becomes `1257ST02BW`. 
This is not happening if I write replace for individual character separately like below:

```
perl -pi -e 's/([\x1])//eg' dummy.txt
perl -pi -e 's/([\x3])//eg' dummy.txt
.....
.....
perl -pi -e 's/([\x1e])//eg' dummy.txt
```

Can anybody please help me with this .

Comment: Try using `/xg` instead of `/eg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
perl -pi -e 's/[\x1\x5\x7\x17\x1a\x1e]//g' dummy.txt
```

or

```
perl -pi -e 'tr/\x1\x5\x7\x17\x1a\x1e//d' dummy.txt
```

You've included spaces in char class definition, so they were removed.